# Goodwillie Calculus II (5.2)

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I'm struggling with statement (5.2) in Goodwillie's Calculus II: Analytic functors. For a map $Y \to X$ of spaces and a nonempty finite set $T$, Goodwillie defines the "fiberwise join" $Y \ast_X T$ to be the homotopy pushout of $Y \leftarrow Y \times T \to X \times T$. There is a natural map $Y \ast_X T \to X$. In (5.2), Goodwillie says that "clearly"

> (5.2): If $Y \to X$ is $(k-1)$-connected, then $Y \ast_X T \to X$ is $k$-connected for nonempty $T$.

This is not clear to me.

**Question:** How does one see that (5.2) holds?

I can see how to reach the weaker conclusion that $Y\ast_X T \to X$ is $(k-1)$-connected as follows. Note that (5.2) is equivalent to saying that

> (5.2, restated): If $Y \to X$ is $(k-1)$-connected, then the square
>   $$\require{AMScd}
> (\ast) \begin{CD}
> Y \times T @>>> X \times T\\ 
> @VVV @VVV\\
> Y @>>> X
> \end{CD}$$
>   is $k$-cocartesian.

Thus one may apply Theorem 2.6 from the same paper. In our case, the relevant facts are that:

- The map $X \times T \to X$ is $(-1)$-connected.
- The map $Y \to X$ is $(k-1)$-connected.
- The square $(\ast)$ is cartesian (i.e. $\infty$-connected).

So Theorem 2.6 tells us that the square $(\ast)$ is $n-1+ \min((-1)+(k-1), \infty)$-connected, with $n=2$. By my arithmetic, this says that $(\ast)$ is $(k-1)$-cocartesian, whereas (5.2) is the stronger claim that $(\ast)$ is $k$-cocartesian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless $T = \varnothing$, then $X \times T \to X$ is actually $0$-connected. Indeed, the induced map $\pi_0(X) \times \pi_0(T) \to \pi_0(X)$ is surjective. (Equivalently, its fiber is $T$, which is $(-1)$-connected... unless it is empty). Which matches up with the assumption in the statement of (5.2), "for nonempty $T$", that you didn't use. So if you do the computation then the square is indeed $k$-connected.

Comment: Thanks. My error was more embarrassing than you indicate -- I had the definitions wrong! I'm just now realizing that "$n$-connected map" is _not_ normalized so that a space $X$ is $n$-connected iff $X \to pt$ is $n$-connected, but rather so that $X$ is $n$-connected iff $pt \to X$ is $n$-connected. This seems like the wrong convention to me since you need a special case for $X = \emptyset$, but there you go.

Comment: No worries. I assume (but I have no proof) that people first defined "connected maps" as maps that hit all the connected components of the target, and since it was awkward to talk about "$(-1)$-connected maps" they instead called them "$0$-connected maps".